# Using additional xsl for each or another xslt element?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing my research for bachelor degree making XSLT 1.0 with Cooktop 2.5 to transform XML files to another. Now, I get stuck again on transforming this form of XML because I'm beginner working with XSLT. I have asked the solution for another problem a few times ago and it's helped me a lot. So I try to find the solution again here. I have a piece XML like this (actually has more SignalLine and InstrumentLoop elements) :

```
<PlantModel>
     <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="P11108P11104" ToID="PIT-108"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="PIT-108" ToID="PI-108"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
        <Connection FromID="PI-108" ToID="PDY-110"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="PI-108" ToID="PDY-111"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="P11107P11104" ToID="PIT-107"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="PIT-107" ToID="PI-107"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="PI-107" ToID="PDY-111"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
        <Connection FromID="PDY-111" ToID="PDI-111"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
        <Connection FromID="P11107P11104" ToID="PIT-109"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
         <Connection FromID="PIT-109" ToID="PI-109"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
        <Connection FromID="PI-109" ToID="PDY-110"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
        <Connection FromID="PDY-110" ToID="PDI-110"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <SignalLine>
        <Connection FromID="PIT-113" ToID="FV-105"/>
    </SignalLine>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PIT-107"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PI-107"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PIT-108"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PI-108"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PIT-109"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PI-109"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PDY-110"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PDI-110"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PDY-111"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PDI-111"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PI-113"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="PIT-113"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
    <InstrumentLoop>
        <Association TagName="FV-105"/>
    </InstrumentLoop>
</PlantModel>
```

I want to make the information from signal line element to be the block. So, I want to classify the instrument loops from P&ID (Piping & Instrument Diagram) XML. I classify it from first letter and the number of @TagName and  SignalLine/Connection element. If the value of @FromID or @ToID from one SignalLine element equal wiht the value of @FromID or @ToID from another SignalLine element, and the value @FromID or @ToID this another element equal with the value @FromID or @ToID of another SignalLine element again, it say they are one instrument loop. So, from the sample I want XML output like this :

```
<Project>
<Models>
    <Block Id="P-107P-108P-109P-110P-111">
        <ModelChildren>
            <Block Id="PIT-107"/>
            <Block Id="PI-107"/>
            <Block Id="PIT-108"/>
            <Block Id="PI-108"/>
            <Block Id="PIT-109"/>
            <Block Id="PI-109"/>
            <Block Id="PDY-110"/>
            <Block Id="PDI-110"/>
            <Block Id="PDY-111"/>
            <Block Id="PDI-111"/>
        </ModelChildren>
    </Block>
</Models>
</Project>
```

I succeed to classify one instrument loop if it just has same first letter and the number of @TagName and if it has 2 diferent first letter and the number of @TagName. Now, I get the problem because one instrument loop has 4 different number of @TagName. I have tried XSLT like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<Project>
<Models>
    <xsl:for-each select = "/PlantModel/SignalLine[(string-length(Connection/@FromID) &lt; 8) and (string-length(Connection/@ToID) &lt; 8)]">

        <xsl:variable name = "ToID" select = "./Connection/@ToID" />    
        <xsl:variable name = "FromID" select = "./Connection/@FromID" />
        <xsl:variable name = "IBDFrom" select = "concat(substring($FromID,1,1),'-',substring-after($FromID,'-'))" />
        <xsl:variable name = "IBDTo" select = "concat(substring($ToID,1,1),'-',substring-after($ToID,'-'))" />
        <xsl:variable name = "CountTo" select = "count(/PlantModel/SignalLine/Connection[((@FromID=$ToID) or (@ToID=$ToID)) and (concat(substring(@FromID,1,1),'-',substring-after(@FromID,'-'))!=concat(substring(@ToID,1,1),'-',substring-after(@ToID,'-')))]) " />

        <xsl:if test = "($IBDTo != $IBDFrom) and ($CountTo &gt; 1)">

            <Block>                 
                <xsl:attribute  name = "Id" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="$IBDFrom" /><xsl:value-of select="$IBDTo" />
                </xsl:attribute>

                 <ModelChildren>

                    <xsl:for-each select = "/PlantModel/InstrumentLoop/Association[(concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'-',substring-after(@TagName,'-'))=$IBDFrom) or (concat(substring(@TagName,1,1),'-',substring-after(@TagName,'-'))=$IBDTo)]">

                        <Block>
                            <xsl:attribute  name = "Id" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="@TagName" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </Block>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ModelChildren>
            </Block>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</Models>
</Project>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And, the output XML is like this, any idea?

```
<Project>
<Models>
    <Block Id="P-109P-110">
        <ModelChildren>
            <Block Id="PIT-109"/>
            <Block Id="PI-109"/>
            <Block Id="PDY-110"/>
            <Block Id="PDI-110"/>
        </ModelChildren>
    </Block>
    <Block Id="P-108P-110">
        <ModelChildren>
            <Block Id="PIT-108"/>
            <Block Id="PI-108"/>
            <Block Id="PDY-110"/>
            <Block Id="PDI-110"/>
        </ModelChildren>
    </Block>
    <Block Id="P-108P-111">
        <ModelChildren>
            <Block Id="PIT-108"/>
            <Block Id="PI-108"/>
            <Block Id="PDY-111"/>
            <Block Id="PDI-111"/>
        </ModelChildren>
    </Block>
    <Block Id="P-107P-111">
        <ModelChildren>
            <Block Id="PIT-107"/>
            <Block Id="PI-107"/>
            <Block Id="PDY-111"/>
            <Block Id="PDI-111"/>
        </ModelChildren>
    </Block>
</Models>
</Project>
```

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: Can you explain the business logic for getting the required output? Also the XSLT shared has errors viz. closed `</xsl:for-each>` having a `select`, `<LBlock>` node (probably a typo). Please share the corrected XSL.

Comment: @AniketV Thank you for your fast response. I'm sorry for typo and I have corrected it. I will try to explain the logic. So, I want to classify the instrument loops from P&ID (Piping & Instrument Diagram) XML. I classify it from first letter and the number of TagName and  SignalLine/Connection element. I succeed to classify one instrument loop if it just has same first letter and the number of TagName (from your last help) and if it has 2 diferent first letter and the number of TagName. Now, I get the problem because one instrument loop has 4 different number of TagName. Is it clear enough?

Comment: The relation between `SignalLine/Connection` and `InstrumentLoop` nodes is still not clear. The sample output shows 10 `<Block>` having values same as the 10 `Association/@TagName` that are in the sample input XML.How does the outer `<Block>` gets generated containing the `id` appended with all the `P` values? Can you reduce the input XML further and using the specific values in the input XML, explain how to arrive at the output.